# What python package to use for UART?

Tags: python, serial

I have connected my GPS EM305 to my Raspberry Pi B+, but i am very lost in getting communication ...

I have used this program

```
import serial

import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART

UART.setup("UART1")

GPS = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyO1', 9600)

while(1):

        while GPS.inWaiting()==0:
                pass
        NMEA=GPS.readline()
        print NMEA
```

From beaglebone, is it correct for the pi?

It said that the module adafruit is not installed, is possible to installed it or should I use something different?

Comment: I don't know what you should be using for the UART module (that one is unlikely to work, although it might if it is based on the generic linux interface) but the actual serial port on the B+ with Raspbian is `/dev/serial0` (or `/dev/ttyAMA0`; the former is a symlink).

Comment: Good information.  And as I commented below, to use a UART for anything other than a console there are further steps to be taken.

Comment: Did you solve your problem Daniel? Please mark an answer correct or provide a solutions. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is PySerial.

Install it using  `apt-get install python-serial`

Then in Python, the syntax is a bit different than you showed, so use it like so:

```
import serial

sp = serial.Serial ("/dev/tty01")   
sp.baudrate = 9600                   

data = sp.read(10)      # 10 characters            
sp.write(data)          # echo all 10 characters back

sp.close()
```

Comment: If you really want to use a UART port, check out this site:  https://electrosome.com/uart-raspberry-pi-python/
it discusses the process required to convert a Pi UART from console to general use, complete with python and command line examples.

Comment: If you look down the page here you will see a very clear diagram that discusses the UART electrical connections.  http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-the-Neo-6M-GPS/

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Goldilocks.  That makes it a lot more clear.  I don't know how you did that but I like the result a lot.